# Oracle SQL - PLS-00049 - bad bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have table defined like this:

```
create table "nakup"  (
   "cislo_n"            INTEGER                         not null,
   "id_zak"             INTEGER                         not null,
   "jm_pobocky"         CHAR(15)                        not null,
   "datum_cas"          DATE                            not null
      constraint CKC_DATUM_CAS_NAKUP check ("datum_cas" >= TO_DATE('1.01.1994 8:30:25', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')),
   constraint PK_NAKUP primary key ("cislo_n")
```

I want to create a trigger that would block inserting a date from the future, my code looks like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "nakup" 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  if (:new.datum_cas > current_timestamp) then
  raise_application_error(-20000, 'Špatně zadané datum a čas.');
end if;
END;
```

I keep getting error Error(5,7): PLS-00049: chybná vázaná proměnná 'NEW.DATUM_CAS' (bad bind variable in english). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you use `:new."datum_cas"`?

Comment: [Quoted identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) are going to cause you pain and Oracle doesn't recommend using them; unless you have a *really* good reason, use unquoted identifiers.

Comment: `"datum_cas"` is a different column name than `datum_cas` which is explained in the chapter "Basic Elements of SQL" in the Oracle manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223

Comment: There is no reason to use `datum_cas` as a quoted identifier. Good practice would be to use **non-quoted identifier**. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/30457938/3989608.  **quoted identifier** uses **double quotation marks** whenever you refer to that object. If you create the object using double-quotation marks, it becomes case sensitive and must be always used the same way wherever the object is referenced.

Comment: Also, 1. avoid using `CHAR`, use `VARCHAR2`. 2. `datum_cas` is **DATE** data type, however, the comparison is made with **current_timestamp**

Answer (score 2):

As Gordon Linoff suggested, your trigger will compile if you enclose the column name in double quotes:

```
create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "nakup" 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  if (:new."datum_cas" > current_timestamp) then
  raise_application_error(-20000, 'Špatně zadané datum a čas.');
end if;
END;
/

Trigger TRIGGER1 compiled
```

[Quoted identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129) have to be quoted everywhere they are referenced. You seem to have realised that when you referred to the table name in the trigger definition, but it applies to the column names too.

Your life will be much simpler if you use unquoted identifiers (or quoted uppercase identifiers, which is the same thing as long as they don't contain any invalid characters). Oracle does not recommend using quoted identifiers for database object names. So this works with no double-quotes at all:

```
create table nakup  (
   cislo_n            INTEGER                         not null,
   id_zak             INTEGER                         not null,
   jm_pobocky         CHAR(15)                        not null,
   datum_cas          DATE                            not null,
   constraint CKC_DATUM_CAS_NAKUP
     check (datum_cas >= TO_DATE('1.01.1994 8:30:25', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')),
   constraint PK_NAKUP primary key (cislo_n)
);

Table NAKUP created.

create or replace TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON nakup
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  if (:new.datum_cas > current_timestamp) then
  raise_application_error(-20000, 'Špatně zadané datum a čas.');
end if;
END;
/

Trigger TRIGGER1 compiled
```

You can then refer to `nakup.datum_cas` etc. in your code, instead of having to use `"nakup"."datum_cas"`.

Comment: Good answer. Another observation is, 1. OP is using `CHAR`instead of `VARCHAR2`. 2. `datum_cas` is **DATE** data type, however, the comparison is made with **current_timestamp**.

Answer (score 0):

yes...

`datum_cas` column name is different from `datum_cas` column name..

Oracle stores column names as uppercase by default,if we use double quotes ("") the column name is stored as-is (upper/lower)

example....

```
SQL> create table test5 (id number,"id1" number);
      table created.

SQL> insert into  test5 values(1,2);

 1 row created.

SQL> select * from  test5;

  ID        id1
----- ----------
    1          2
```

id is stored as ID and id1 is stored as id1.